# Is it good Idea to use HAProxy for normal forwardProxy ?

Tags: haproxy, http-proxy

We are setting up proxy servers for an enterprise account. Which is going to be used as one stop shop for all internet out request.
I know HAProxy can be used whereas Squid is also an option. Can someone please provide a better understanding on which one to use? 
I also dont see a proper implementation guide to configure the forward proxy using HAProxy.

Thanks 
Praveen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *I know HAProxy can be used*

This isn't accurate, because HAProxy is not a forward proxy.  It is only a reverse proxy.

HAProxy can, of course, be used as a load balancer in front of a set of forward proxies if desired, but you would still need another piece of software, such as squid, to provide the actual forward proxy service.

Comment: I was able to use HAProxy as forward proxy for HTTP. But facing SSL error for HTTPS. My question and config is here https://stackoverflow.com/q/68321275/6587774. Help if you can